# display master page over navigation bar in xamarin forms droid project

Tags: android, material-design, xamarin.forms, master-detail, navigationbar

For those of you used to code in Java for Android, I believe you'll immediatly understand this concept, while others might not, but it's ok, I'll do my best to try and explain what I mean.

I have this project, company one, to deliver at work, in which I have to develop an App that, among other things, contains the Navigation Drawer concept form material design, but adapted to the company's adm favorite "concept" of development, i.e., Xamarin (Forms, in this case)... using Xamarin, well, almost the same thing but it's manageable to achieve the required, but in Forms?.... well, lets just say they didn't yet understand the concept behind it (child's play apps, most likely) and require a B2C app, very professional-like, developed with THAT... -_-

Anyways, among a huge series of other issues I've managed to find and have to face, is this: the nav drawer (a.k.a. here Master Page) needs to be displayed over the AppCompatBar (here Navigation Bar), because, well, because that's what is supposed to be felt using Android, that's how it works with every other app, that's how it was designed to work, and how it must work, but guess what? no go in Xamarin Forms...

I've tried the https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/, several blogs and forums in the web (except theirs, of course, as I'm still waiting for a very simple answer after 3 months, and the project must soon be presented as demo), their book "Creating
Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms" by Charles Petzold, online videos, and nothing, not a clue on how to display the master page over the navigation bar when it's called...

Here's the code for the main page in xaml:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile.UI.Pages;assembly=Mobile"
              x:Class="Mobile.UI.Pages.MainPage"
              BackgroundColor="White"
              IsGestureEnabled="False"
              MasterBehavior="Default">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage
        BarBackgroundColor="#27C6E5">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:ItemListPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

The master page also in xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Mobile.UI.Pages.MasterPage"
         Icon="menu.png"
         Title="Menu">

<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" />
</ContentPage.Padding>

<StackLayout
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="Fill"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        HeightRequest="128"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        Padding="4">

        <Image
            Source="favicon.png"
            HeightRequest="128"
            WidthRequest="200"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>

    <ListView
        x:Name="menuList"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        SeparatorVisibility="None"
        HasUnevenRows="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell
                    ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}"
                    Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Its code-behind:

```
public ListView ListView
    {
        get
        {
            return menuList;
        }
    }

    public MasterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Padding = 0;

        var menuListItems = new List<MenuListItem>();

        menuListItems.Add(new MenuListItem()
        {
            Title = "Items",
            IconSource = "items.png",
            TargetType = typeof(ItemListPage)
        });

        menuListItems.Add(new MenuListItem()
        {
            Title = "Chat",
            IconSource = "chat.png",
            TargetType = typeof(ChatListPage)
        });

        menuList.ItemsSource = menuListItems;
    }
```

And my main page:

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        masterPage.ListView.ItemTapped += ListView_ItemTapped;

        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
        {
            Master.Icon = "menu.png";
        }
    }

    private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.Item as MenuListItem;

        if (item != null)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType))
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(204, 204, 204),
                Title = item.Title
            };

            masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;

            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Anything else you might need, please just ask...

Any help, please?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this for me was to make sure that the Android activity inherited from FormsAppCompatActivity.

[This](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) blog post set us on the right track.

Comment: yes, I've seen this blog, and another one with a little more info even regarding the icon, but this are things I'm not supposed to mess with. Figure this, I have to use something tottaly diff from the concepts behind google Android, that tries to mask Android, without even ever lay a finger on the Android itself... -_- I can't begin to understand if it's just fanatism or lack of capacity to understand that things such as limitations do exist (specially talking about windows universe)...

Comment: even so, thank you very much for your answer. If you don't mind, I'll share it with who's in charge of this proj, in order to try to make a point regarding delivery to Android users, and to be able to use a little more of the original resources...

Comment: one more thing, how did you manage to have formsappcompatactivity working? the thing is that I tried the method in the blog post you mentioned, but I could never find the resource toolbar or tabs to set formsappcompatactivity toolbar resource and tab resource properties...